# Why are item names converted to upper case when saving?

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, xpages-ssjs

My designer client is 8.5.3FP6 and Notes server is 8.5.3FP6.

When I save document in Xpage the field name is changes from proper case to all upper case for certain field. The field name on the Notes form is in proper case like "Doc_Stage_TX" but when checked in the notes client thru document properties it is "DOC_STAGE_TX". Anybody experience this behaviour?

Here is a SSJS code for saving:

```
document1.setValue("Section1_CompletedBy",unm);
@SetField("Section1DateCompleted",@Today())
document1.setValue("Section1Status","Marketing Check completed");
document1.setValue("Doc_Stage_TX","Stage 2");
document1.save();
```

All those field name are in uppercase after saving.

Comment: Are you running form validation? Maybe the field is named in upper case on the form?

Comment: No I'm not running form validation. One field is in edit box which has style="display:none" and 3 other are visible but read only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is consistent behavior of Notes for a rather long time: when you create a new item programmatically  `@SetField` or `.setValue(...)` do that, then the item name is all upperCase. Only when an item is created via a field in a form (binding), or using `.replaceItemValue()` case is preserved

Comment: Exactly. @Mohan Use .replaceItemValue()

Comment: Thanks. I'm not creating new item but rather using the existing item to set value thru Xpage ssjs. I'm saving lot of existing items and only these 4 existing items names are converted to uppercase.

Comment: `setValue` calls `replaceItemValue` behind the scenes anyway, but after doing some type coercion...

Comment: I'm working on a workflow application and using the field value in control and validation. If xpage keep changing the existing item name randomly, then I've to look for those changed item names on everyday basis and change my code accordingly which is not a good practice.

Comment: If you use replaceItemValue() you are save and getItemvalue() or hasItem() isn't case sensitive

Comment: Does it work for you now? Feel free to accept the answer